# Get Min and Max of rows that are grouped by Day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to return the Min and Max for each record that is grouped by Day with Laravel Eloquent, so here it goes:

Table Structure: **Rate**

```
id     buy_rate     sell_rate     market_currency_id     created_at
==     ========     =========     ==================     ==========
1      10           7             44                     2020-10-10
2      10           9             44                     2020-10-10
3      10           8             44                     2020-10-10
4      10           12            44                     2020-10-11
5      10           14            44                     2020-10-11
6      10           13            44                     2020-10-11
```

Right now I am getting data like this:

```
$rates = Rate::
select('sell_rate', \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y-%m-%d) day))
->where('market_currency_id', '=', 44)
->whereBetween('created_at', [2020-10-10, 2020-10-11])
->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
->get()
->toArray();
```

The above code returns:

```
0 => array:2 [▼
    "sell_rate" => "8"
    "day" => "2010-10-10"
]
1 => array:2 [▼
    "sell_rate" => "12"
    "day" => "2010-10-11"
]
```

Now, what I want is to get something like this:

```
0 => array:2 [▼
    "sell_rate" => "8"
    "day" => "2010-10-10"
    "min_rate" => "7"
    "max_rate" => "9"

]
1 => array:2 [▼
    "sell_rate" => "13"
    "day" => "2010-10-11"
    "min_rate" => "12"
    "max_rate" => "14"
]
```

I tried many ways but I couldn't get what I wanted, I tried a raw select like this:

```
$rates = Rate::
select('sell_rate', \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y-%m-%d) day))
->selectRaw("MIN(sell_rate) AS min_rate, MAX(sell_rate) AS max_rate")
->where('market_currency_id', '=', 44)
->whereBetween('created_at', [2020-10-10, 2020-10-11])
->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
->get()
->toArray();
```

But couldn't get what I wanted, I also can't do it separately because there are thousands of rows, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also group by the day:

```
$rates = Rate::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y-%m-%d) day"))
    ->selectRaw("MIN(sell_rate) AS min_rate, MAX(sell_rate) AS max_rate")
    ->where('market_currency_id', '=', 44)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2020-10-10', '2020-10-11'])
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('day'))
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('day'))
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$rates = Rate::
select('sell_rate', \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y-%m-%d) day"), \DB::raw("MIN(sell_rate) as min_rate"), \DB::raw("MAX(sell_rate) as max_rate"))
->where('market_currency_id', '=', 44)
->whereBetween('created_at', [2020-10-10, 2020-10-11])
->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
->groupBy(DB::raw('day'))
->get()
->toArray();
```